# Pandas save data based on column in xlsx\csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I want to use PANDAS to save the processed data in the original format into another xlsx\csv file.

for,example,I have 1 xlsx file

```
num1,num2
1,   4
2,   5
3,   6
80,  120
```

if I use `series1.to_excel('004.xlsx',index=False)` , the result in the 004.xlsx file is

```
num2
4
5
6
3.75
```

The num1 column data has not saved to the file.And if I use `series1.to_csv('004.csv',mode='a',index=False)`, the result in the 004.xlsx file is

```
num1
1
2
3
2.5
num2
4
5
6
3.75
```

I want the output format saved in the xlsx\csv file to be something like this

```
num1,num2
1,   4
2,   5
3,   6
2.5, 3.75
```

COULD YOU HELP ME?Here is all my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_excel = pd.read_excel('002.xlsx')
df = df_excel
for col in df.columns:
    df_current_col = df[col]
    series1 = pd.Series(df_current_col)
    s = (series1.quantile(0.75)-series1.quantile(0.25))
    iqr = 3 * s
    val_low = series1.quantile(0.25) - iqr*0.5
    val_up = series1.quantile(0.25) + iqr*0.5
    outlier = series1[(series1 > val_up)|(series1 < val_low)]
    normal_val = series1[(series1 < val_up)|(series1 > val_low)]
    outlier = np.array(outlier)
    sum = 0
    normal_val = np.array(normal_val)
    for i in range(len(normal_val)):
        sum+=normal_val[i]
    mean = sum / (len(normal_val))
    if outlier is  None:
        print('NONE')
    else:
        for i ,val in enumerate(series1):
            series1[i] = float(np.where((((val < val_low) | (val > val_up))), mean, val))
        ########
        #series1.to_excel('004.xlsx',index=False)
        series1.to_csv('004.csv',mode='a',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
df_excel = pd.read_excel('002.xlsx')
df = df_excel
Storeage = []
for col in df.columns:
    df_current_col = df[col]
    series1 = pd.Series(df_current_col)
    s = (series1.quantile(0.75)-series1.quantile(0.25))
    iqr = 3 * s
    val_low = series1.quantile(0.25) - iqr*0.5
    val_up = series1.quantile(0.25) + iqr*0.5
    outlier = series1[(series1 > val_up)|(series1 < val_low)]
    normal_val = series1[(series1 < val_up)|(series1 > val_low)]
    outlier = np.array(outlier)
    sum = 0
    normal_val = np.array(normal_val)
    for i in range(len(normal_val)):
        sum+=normal_val[i]
    mean = sum / (len(normal_val))
    for i, val in enumerate(series1):
        series1[i] = float(np.where((((val < val_low) | (val > val_up))), mean, val))
    Storeage.append(series1)
print(Storeage)
res = pd.concat(Storeage,axis=1)
res.to_excel('004.xlsx',index=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append multiple 1D list to a CSV file. Instead you should be trying to append one 2D list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
df_excel = pd.read_excel('002.xlsx')
df = df_excel
Storeage = []
for col in df.columns:
    df_current_col = df[col]
    series1 = pd.Series(df_current_col)
    s = (series1.quantile(0.75)-series1.quantile(0.25))
    iqr = 3 * s
    val_low = series1.quantile(0.25) - iqr*0.5
    val_up = series1.quantile(0.25) + iqr*0.5
    outlier = series1[(series1 > val_up)|(series1 < val_low)]
    normal_val = series1[(series1 < val_up)|(series1 > val_low)]
    outlier = np.array(outlier)
    sum = 0
    normal_val = np.array(normal_val)
    for i in range(len(normal_val)):
        sum+=normal_val[i]
    mean = sum / (len(normal_val))
    if outlier is  None:
        print('NONE')
    else:
        for i ,val in enumerate(series1):
            series1[i] = float(np.where((((val < val_low) | (val > val_up))), mean, val))
        ########
        #series1.to_excel('004.xlsx',index=False)
        Storeage.append(series1.tolist()) #turning List on side so it looks correct
Storeage = np.array(Storeage).T.tolist()
with open('Output.csv', 'w') as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",") #appending each row of the 2D list to a csv file
    writer.writerows(Storeage)
```

Comment: Sir, after running your code and saving the results to an XLSX file, there are two problems occur. One is that the corresponding column name is not saved with it into the .xlsx file. Second, there is a blank line between each row of data and another row. I was inspired by your code, and have solved the problem. The solution to the problem is placed in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_excel = pd.read_excel('002.xlsx')
df = df_excel
def transformer(series1):
    s = (series1.quantile(0.75)-series1.quantile(0.25))
    iqr = 3 * s
    val_low = series1.quantile(0.25) - iqr*0.5
    val_up = series1.quantile(0.25) + iqr*0.5
    outlier = series1[(series1 > val_up)|(series1 < val_low)]
    normal_val = series1[(series1 < val_up)|(series1 > val_low)]
    outlier = np.array(outlier)
    sum = 0
    normal_val = np.array(normal_val)
    for i in range(len(normal_val)):
        sum+=normal_val[i]
    mean = sum / (len(normal_val))
    if outlier is  None:
        print('NONE')
    else:
        for i ,val in enumerate(series1):
            series1[i] = float(np.where((((val < val_low) | (val > val_up))), mean, val))
        return series1
        ########
df = df.apply(transformer , axis=1)
#df.to_excel('004.xlsx',index=False)
df.to_csv('004.csv',mode='w',index=False)
```